# php curl connect with ssl cert fails

Tags: php, ssl, curl

I am trying to connect to a server using ssl cert verification.  on my local machine i run curl in verbose and i get:

```
*   Trying X.X.X.X...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to server.com (X.X.X.X) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/ssl/cert.pem
      CApath: ./XXX.pem
* SSL connection using TLSv1.2 / ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
......<<connects correctly and does it's thing>>......
```

on my other linux box i do the exact same script and get:

```
* About to connect() to server.com port 443 (#0)
*   Trying X.X.X.X...
* Connected to server.com (X.X.X.X) port 443 (#0)
* Initializing NSS with certpath: sql:/etc/pki/nssdb
* Closing connection 0
 << Curl error: 77 >>
```

I am using the exact same certs on both machines.  I have tried a billion different things and cant figure it out.

What do i need to do on the failing machine to get it to connect correctly? What other info do you need to assist me.  I am quite far out of my comfort zone on this one...I dont know if its a local cert on the machine thats causing the error....

here is the script I am using:

```
    $path = "./someFile.pem";
    $keyFile = "./someFile.key";
    $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLCERT, $path);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLKEY, $keyFile);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLCERTPASSWD , $pass);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAPATH, $path);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 300);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xml);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CERTINFO, true);
        $response = curl_exec($ch);
```

EDIT***

I was given a pfx file and i did the following:

to export the private key: openssl pkcs12 -in certname.pfx -nocerts -out key.pem -nodes

to export the certificate: openssl pkcs12 -in certname.pfx -nokeys -out cert.pem

to remove the passphrase from the private key: openssl rsa -in key.pem -out server.key

I then put each of those files in the dir that httpd.conf expects.  access to the server works fine now over https://.

I did yum install ca-certifcates and got:

```
Package ca-certificates-2019.2.32-76.el7_7.noarch already installed and latest version
```

I dont know what else to do next.  getting same error as above.

Comment: Look up what Curl error 77 means. Your root certs are missing or outdated. What distro are you running?

Comment: So i read what 77 means, but don't quite understand. like i said, this is not my cup of tea. google lead me to this step: "Add it as a new file to /etc/pki/ca-trust/source/anchors/: cp foo.crt /etc/pki/ca-trust/source/anchors/".  where do i get foo.crt?

Comment: NO. STOP. ABORT. Anyone telling you to put certificates there has no idea what they're doing. Yes, I know there are a lot of them in the top google results. It might stop the error, but it's not a fix, and is a _horrible_ one at that. Remove whatever certs you put in there and use yum to install or update the `ca-certificates` package.

Comment: see edit in original question please